# Definition of the dimension of a Noetherian integral scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Noetherian integral scheme with generic point $\eta$, and let $x_0\rightsquigarrow\cdots\rightsquigarrow x_n$ and  $y_0\rightsquigarrow\cdots\rightsquigarrow y_m$ be maximal chains of specializations. Must $n=m$? If this isn't true in general, is it true if we replace $X$ with $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ for an algebraically closed field $k$?

Comment: Might a non-catenary ring give a counterexample?

Comment: I know very little about such rings.

Comment: There are infinite dimensional Noetherian rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the generality you state, this is false. For example take $X$ to be the spectrum of the Noetherian ring $k[[x]][y]$, with $k$ a field. Then you have chain $0\subset (x)\subset (x,y)$, of length 2 which is maximal. You also have a maximal chain $0\subset (xy-1)$.

For $\mathbb{A}^n_k$, $k$ any field, this true, for example use Noether Normalization.

Comment: Is there any property of a scheme that can guarantee the condition? I.e. being projective over a field?

Comment: Any integral scheme which is finite type over a field has this property.

Comment: Why is true for $\mathbb{A}_k^n$? I'm struggling to find a reference for that.

Comment: I suggest you read a text book-for example Serre's Local Algebra, where it is proved that any maximal prime ideal chain in a finitely generated algebra, which is a domain has length equal to the transcendence degree of the fraction filed over the base field.

Comment: What page number?

Comment: come on! You can't loose by reading the whole book.